# Slow down timeline in Pivot View

Tags: excel, data-visualization, excel-2013, powerview, pivot-chart

I have been using timeline in Pivot View in Excel 2013. In the play axis I have place year. The timeline rolls very fast such that I even cannot get an idea about how the data is changing over the years.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you are talking about controlling the speed of the play axis for scatter graphs in Power View. You can only control what attribute you put in the play axis. If you have three years worth of data and put a Year attribute in the play axis it will run quite fast across the 3 points. If you put in a WeekEnding value however, you will notice that it plays much more slowly, this time across 156 points.

You can also pause the play of course, or double-click the bubbles to see how each one progresses.